# How to select multiple images from mobile app gallery using ionic and react

Tags: reactjs, ionic4

I am trying to create a sample application that will either take a picture from camera, or select an multiple image from gallery (depending open the option)  and show on the screen by using ionic and react. i tried google it but couldn't get proper answer. any help or lead will be appreciated.